# How was this black and white photograph of a calm ocean done?

Tags: black-and-white, reverse-engineering

How can I create photographs with the characteristics of this image?

[image]

Comment: What 'effect' in the image are you specifically looking to replicate?  What qualities?

Comment: the whole look of it really. The black sky and then the white middle with the grey water. To get the water so smoooth, do I use a long exposure?

Comment: Are you looking to do it in camera, in post, or whatever works?

Comment: Rohan Reilly does photography in this style, and often includes technical information on Flickr, e.g. http://www.flickr.com/photos/selectah/6452702353/in/set-72157626836720907/ He uses a strong neutral density filter (mentioned in other photos) to achieve the 1-2 minute exposure times.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several effects going on here.

- The water effect must be done in camera, with a very long exposure. Probably during dusk or at night otherwise you'll have too much light, even with a strong ND filter.
- The black and white conversion can be done in camera if shooting JPEG but is better done in post.
- The gradient in the sky is either done with a coloured filter (e.g. red or organge), a graduated ND, or in post. It could also just be atmospheric conditions.
- Soft lighting comes from an overcast sky.

Comment: The dark sky could also be an effect of shooting in infrared. The sky looks dark in IR, with a gradient like that at the horizons, as the thickness of the atmosphere begins to overwhelm the sky.

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't stack neutral density filters to extend exposure times arbitrarily long?  Also, would multiple filters even be strictly needed?  For visual observation of the Sun through a telescope/binoculars you can get filters that reduce brightness by 100,000x.  I'd think that would be sufficient to allow multi-second daylight exposures without doing anything else.

Comment: @Dan stacking ND filters eventually causes colour shifts and loss of sharpness, and vignetting on full frame. I would question the affect on image quality of shooting through a filter designed for viewing the sun. To get the sea that flat you need to expose for about 15 minutes, not a few seconds! I've seen a few shots like this and they were all done at night.

Comment: @MattGrum Baaders AstroSolar filter material is supposed to have a neutral color balance (other common filter types do have major color balance shifts); but a quick search didn't turn up any numbers for how strict their definition of neutral is.